# Transformation of the histogram

Tags: probability, transformation

I have two classes in my problem: 'missing' and 'present'. These are the pixel intensities of some pictures. The histogram of their values you can see below. I would like to find some transformation that would allow me to separate these two classes (e.g. missing gets shifted to the left and 'present' to the right). Is it possible to do and if yes, how?

[image].

Comment: why not add 2 to the present values?

Comment: @gt6989b I forgot to mention, that initially we do not know whether a set of pixels belongs to 'missing' or 'present'

Comment: If you would like to classify the two classes mixture solely based on the frequencies of the histogram, then I guess the best bet will be computing the "likelihood ratio" between two classes for each bin. For example, in one of the bin with large value, the ratio of Present to Missing is $9:1$. If you classify all of them as Present then you know $10\%$ of them are mis-classified as Present but actually Missing. If you randomly classify $90\%$ to Present and $10\%$ to Missing, then on average $81\%$ & $1\%$ is correctly classified to Present & Missing. Depends on the cost of mis-classification